# Regular expression python re.sub

Tags: python

Following are three reqular expressions with slight modifications. Can anyone explain the difference?

```
# 1.
print(re.sub(r"a(\d{4})","A\1","a2134"))
# Output-->A.

# 2.
print(re.sub(r"a(\d{4})","A","a2134"))
# Output-->A

# 3.
print(re.sub(r"a(\d{4})",r"A\1","a2134"))
# Output-->A2134
```

Comment: Do you understand what raw strings are?

Comment: Then I don't quite get what you're asking.  In your first example, `"A\1"` is not a raw string.  In the third example, `r"A\1"` is a raw string.  If you know what that means, you should understand the difference.  (The second example isn't really related.)  If there's something specific you don't understand about the output, please say what it is, and say what you expect the output to be instead.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between first and third because in Eclipse, in sublime and in idle am getting output.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you didn't use raw string.  That means that you replaced your string with A\x01 (print '\1' outputs \x01) so that's the output you should see
In the third example you used raw string.  That means that re.sub received A\1 ( and not \x01) as it's input and it replaces \1 with the first group that it found in the source string 
The second example isn't really related. You just replace your string with A

Comment: In third example, print(re.sub(r"a(\d{4})",r"A\2","a2134a1234")),[i changed 1 to 2] am getting error. why is it so?

Comment: It fails because you only have 1 group in your regex, so there is nothing to put  instead of \2. In other words the \number in regex takes that group from the regex, not that occurrence if the regex in the string.  Your regex will work if you do

Comment: (accidentally pressed send) print re.sub("a(\d{4})a(\d{4})", "A\2", "a1234a4321")  this will output  A4321